# What is the difference between searching for a char in a char[] vs searching for a String using the String.indexOf() method?

Tags: java, string, char

```
private static int getTotalWordValue(String word) {
    int totalWordValue = 0;

    // Code that produces correct results.
    for(int i=0; i < alpha.length(); i++) {
        char letter = alpha.charAt(i);
        for(char ch: word.toCharArray()) {
            if(letter == ch) {
                totalWordValue += i+1;
            }
        }
    }

    // Code that produces incorrect results.
    totalWordValue = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < alpha.length(); i++) {
        String letter = String.valueOf(alpha.charAt(i)); // <-- here?
        if(word.indexOf(letter) != -1) {
            totalWordValue += i+1;
        }
    }

    return totalWordValue;
}
```

Upon running the above code to solve [Project Euler Problem 42](https://projecteuler.net/problem=42), I am getting different results. The first 'for' loop shown above outputs the correct results and the second 'for' loop outputs incorrect results.

The above code takes a String and returns its word value. For example, the word SKY will return a word value of 55 as the letters in this word add as follows (starting at 1):

- S = 19 (19th position of the alphabet)
- K = 11 (11th position of the alphabet)
- Y = 25 (25th position of the alphabet).

19 + 11 + 25 = 55.

I have reduced the problem to the above code and do not understand why this occurs. Perhaps I have missed an important piece of information as it relates to the Java String class and its methods.

I am running Java 8 in Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) on Windows 10.

Comment: Not sure what exactly is your question. Can you post only specific code ?

Comment: What is the difference between using the first block of code and the second block of code? To me, they should essentially result to the same totalWordValue. But when run on a list of words, they don't come to the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two pieces of code are entirely different.

In both cases you have an outer loop which serves up each character of the string `alpha` in the variable `letter`.

In the first case, you then have an inner loop which runs through **every** character of the string `word` and counts **every** matching occurrence of `letter`. When the inner loop has counted **every** occurrence of `letter` in `word`, the outer loop moves on to the next `letter`.

In the second case, there's no inner loop.  Each time around the outer loop you use `word.indexOf(letter)` to try to find the index of the **first occurrence** of `letter` in `word`. If there is one, you advance your count.  Either way, you're now done with that `letter` and the outer loop moves on to the next `letter`.  There might have been other occurrences of `letter` in `word`, but this case didn't try to find them and count them.

Answer (score 1):

The word value is incorrect in the second implementation for words that contain some letters multiple times. For example for WOOD,
the first method will calculate 3 + 14 + 14 + 22, but the second will calculate 3 + 14 + 22.

Why? The first method iterates over characters of the *word*:

> ```
> for(char ch: word.toCharArray()) {
>     if(letter == ch) {
>         totalWordValue += i+1;
>     }
> }
> ```

The second method iterates over characters of the *alphabet*:

> ```
> for(int i=0; i < alpha.length(); i++) {
>     String letter = String.valueOf(alpha.charAt(i)); // <-- here?
>     if(word.indexOf(letter) != -1) {
>         totalWordValue += i+1;
>     }
> }
> ```

So in the example of "WOOD",
"O" will be counted only once, instead of twice.

---

As an aside,
the conversion to `String` is pointless here:

> ```
> String letter = String.valueOf(alpha.charAt(i));
> if(word.indexOf(letter) != -1) {
> ```

A better way to write the same thing:

```
char letter = alpha.charAt(i);
if (word.indexOf(letter) != -1) {
```

(But the implementation would still be incorrect.)

---

Finally,
if the alphabet is English A-Z, then a faster implementation is possible:

```
int totalWordValue = 0;
for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
  if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') {
    totalWordValue += (c - 'A') + 1;
  }
}

return totalWordValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

**[`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int))** has 4 overloaded method and one of them except `character` argument and return the index of the first occurrence of the character in the character sequence.

Now, coming to you question. In your scenario `indexOf` and `charAt` will behave same because you are passing ONLY character. And, since internally, But, imagine, you have a `String` and you wanted to check and get the index of it from another long `String`. Then what would you do ? There comes `indexOf`

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't necessarily solve your question about the differences between the mentioned methods, but others have answered well enough on that.

You want the sum of the positions in the alphabet of the letters of a String? We can do that in one loop with some arithmetic, without the added overhead of the inner loops or the `alpha` constant.

Like so:

```
public static int getWordValue(String word) {
    int value = 0; //total word value
    for(char c : word.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) { //iterate over character array of lower case string
            int charAsInt = (int) c; //cast char to int, giving the ASCII value
            if(charAsInt <= 122 && charAsInt >= 97) { //122 is the ASCII value of 'z', and 97 is 'a'
                value += (charAsInt - 96); //only subtract 96 because we want 'a' to be 1, not 0
            }
     }
    return value;
}
```

If the reason this works is unclear to you now, it will become evident upon examining an ASCII to decimal table. Let's check one out.

[image: ASCII to decimal table]

Make note of the values of lowercase 'a' and lowercase 'z'. They are our lower and upper bounds, respectively. We simply loop over each lower case character, converting it to its ASCII decimal value with an `int` cast. Then we subtract our ASCII value by the value of 'a', minus one.